# Subtracting dates and get difference in days.How to subtract them?

Tags: java, date, date-difference

can anyone tell how to subtract string "after" from "today" to get days difference.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){


SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
String today=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(today);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 20);
String After=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(After);

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037654/subtract-two-dates-in-java seems related to this.

Comment: [Example using JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021)

Comment: [JodaTime AND Java 8 Time API example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255811/start-date-and-end-date-between-two-dates/25255894#25255894)

Comment: @amitbhardwaj I'd agree with, but that's only half the question...

Comment: your code is working @WannaBeCoder thankx

Comment: I deleted it because of @MadProgrammer comment. I guess you should cross verify and check if it there is a better way.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder JodaTime or Java 8's Time API

Comment: sure @WannaBeCoder but i only need a rough guess..
but for those who need accurate result they should'nt do this

Comment: @MadProgrammer agree but the OP is also not clear what is the diff between 8 march 11 pm to 10 march 2 am he want this as 1 day or the real diff is 3 days

Comment: @amitbhardwaj Unfortunately, that's where the OP will need to use the values returned by `Duration` or `Period` to make their choices... ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer unfortunately `Period` class is in java 8 only so if he is using earlier version he is restricted to use `Duration`

Comment: @amitbhardwaj There's a `Period` and `Duration` class in JodaTime...

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier with java8 where you dont need to subtract long values represent of date and change back to days,  hours and minutes.

```
Date today= LocalDate.now();
Date futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
long days = Period.between(today, futureDate).getDays();
```

[`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) & [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class are available in #java8

`LocalDate` docs

> LocalDate is an immutable date-time object that represents a date,
>   often viewed as year-month-day. Other date fields, such as
>   day-of-year, day-of-week and week-of-year, can also be accessed. For
>   example, the value "2nd October 2007" can be stored in a LocalDate.

---

If you are not using java8, use joda-time library's [`org.joda.time.Days`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) utility to calculate this

```
Days day = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
int days = d.getDays();
```

Comment: If you're up to it and want to add an example using JodaTime, I'll delete my answer +1 to you though

Answer (score 3):

Using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), in case you don't have Java 8

```
String timeValue = "2014/11/11";
DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy/MM/dd").toFormatter();
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(timeValue, parseFormat);
LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusDays(20);

System.out.println(startDate + "; " + endDate);

Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate);
System.out.println("Days = " + p.getDays());
System.out.println("Weeks = " + p.getWeeks());
System.out.println("Months = " + p.getMonths());
```

Which outputs...

```
2014-11-11; 2014-12-01
Days = 6
Weeks = 2
Months = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

May it helps you.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

// compute the difference between two dates.

public class DateDiff {
  public static void main(String[] av) {
    /** The date at the end of the last century */
    Date d1 = new GregorianCalendar(2010, 10, 10, 11, 59).getTime();

    /** Today's date */
    Date today = new Date();

    // Get msec from each, and subtract.
    long diff = today.getTime() - d1.getTime();

    System.out.println("The 21st century (up to " + today + ") is "
        + (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + " days old.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help You..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    String today=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(today);

    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 20);
    String After=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(After);

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(today);
        d2 = format.parse(After);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    System.out.println("Difference is "+diffDays+" Days");
```

Comment: No, never do this.  There are to many variances in how date/time works (leap years, century and millennium boundaries) to simply subtract the millisecond offsets of two dates