# How to determine a date in between Friday and Sunday of the week at a particular time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, simpledateformat, range-checking

I'm trying to check a current date and time is in between Friday 17:42 and Sunday 17:42 of the week with Java.

At the moment I'm doing this with really really bad code block. It was a hurry solution. Now I'm refactoring but I couldn't find any method in joda or etc.

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
private final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
private final int day = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
private final int hour = currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
private final int minute = currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

if (day != 1 && day != 6 && day != 7) {
    if (combined != 0) {
        return badge == 1;
    } else {
        return badge == product;
    }
} else {
    if (day == 6 && hour > 16) {
        if (hour == 17 && minute < 43) {
            if (combined != 0) {
                return badge == 1;
            } else {
                return badge == product;
            }
        } else {
            return badge == 0;
        }
    } else if (day == 6 && hour < 17) {
        if (combined != 0) {
            return badge == 1;
        } else {
            return badge == product;
        }
    } else if (day == 1 && hour > 16) {
        if (hour == 17 && minute < 43) {
            return badge == 0;
        } else {
            if (combined != 0) {
                return badge == 1;
            } else {
                return badge == product;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return badge == 0;
    }
}
```

I've used the solution like thiswith the help of @MadProgrammer and @Meno Hochschild

Method:

```
public static boolean isBetween(LocalDateTime check, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime) {
 return ((check.equals(startTime) || check.isAfter(startTime)) && (check.equals(endTime) || check.isBefore(endTime))); }
```

Usage:

```
static LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
static LocalDateTime friday = now.with(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY).toLocalDate().atTime(17, 41);
static LocalDateTime sunday = friday.plusDays(2).plusMinutes(1);

if (!isBetween(now, friday, sunday)) { ... }
```

Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Well, I might be look at `equals`, `before` and `after`...

Comment: Something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255811/start-date-and-end-date-between-two-dates/25255894#25255894) or [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677541/date-range-in-date-range/20678485#20678485)

Comment: One possible solution - Find "last Friday" and "next Sunday", calculate the difference between the, they should be 172800 seconds apart (yes, I calculated).  If the difference between the two dates is not equal to 172800, you've not within those two dates...

Comment: Generally it is better to define your time range using the "Half-Open" approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So you would define the ending as the moment you *do not* want in your results, Sunday 17:43:00.0. Then compare ( >= beginning AND < ending ). One benefit is that you avoid problems with granularities of fractional second in various data sources, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` and `Calendar` have methods that can perform comparisons on other instances of `Date`/`Calendar`, `equals`, `before` and `after`

However, I'd encourage the use of Java 8's new Time API

```
public static boolean isBetween(LocalDateTime check, LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime) {
    return ((check.equals(startTime) || check.isAfter(startTime)) && 
                    (check.equals(endTime) || check.isBefore(endTime)));
}
```

Which will return `true` if the supplied `LocalDateTime` is within the specified range inclusively.

Something like...

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
start = start.withDayOfMonth(26).withHour(17).withMinute(42).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
LocalDateTime end = start.plusDays(2);

LocalDateTime check = LocalDateTime.now();

System.out.println(check + " is within range = " + isBetween(check, start, end));
check = start;
System.out.println(check + " is within range = " + isBetween(check, start, end));
check = end;
System.out.println(check + " is within range = " + isBetween(check, start, end));
check = start.plusDays(1);
System.out.println(check + " is within range = " + isBetween(check, start, end));
check = end.plusMinutes(1);
System.out.println(check + " is within range = " + isBetween(check, start, end));
```

Which outputs

```
2015-06-25T18:31:32.969 is within range = false
2015-06-26T17:42 is within range = true
2015-06-28T17:42 is within range = true
2015-06-27T17:42 is within range = true
2015-06-28T17:43 is within range = false
```

Joda-Time has an `Interval` class which makes it even eaiser

```
Interval targetInterval = new Interval(targetStart, targetEnd);
System.out.println("Contains interval = " + interval.contains(targetInterval)
```

which is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677541/date-range-in-date-range/20678485#20678485)

## A different approach...

So I was thinking on way home, assuming all you have is the date/time you want to check, how you might determine if the day falls within your range

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
boolean isBetween = false;
switch (now.getDayOfWeek()) {
    case FRIDAY:
    case SATURDAY:
    case SUNDAY:
        LocalDateTime lastFriday = getLastFriday(now);
        LocalDateTime nextSunday = getNextSunday(now);
        isBetween = isBetween(now, lastFriday, nextSunday);
        System.out.println(lastFriday + " - " + nextSunday + ": " + end);
        break;
}
```

What this does is checks the `dayOfWeek` to see if it's within the desired range, if it is, it finds the previous `Friday` and next `Sunday` from the specified date and checks to see if it falls between them (see the previous example)

`lastFriday` and `nextSunday` simply adds/subtracts a `day` from the specified date/time until to reaches the desired `dayOfWeek`, it then seeds the required time constraints

```
public static LocalDateTime getLastFriday(LocalDateTime anchor) {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(anchor);
    return ldt.with(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY).withHour(17).withMinute(42).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
}

public static LocalDateTime getNextSunday(LocalDateTime anchor) {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(anchor);
    return ldt.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY).withHour(17).withMinute(42).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
}
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts. But are you sure that your code is equivalent to the old code posted by the OP? Consider for example the case now=Sunday-17:42:30.

Comment: @MenoHochschild as far as I've tested, because a zero out the seconds and nano seconds, anything after 17:42 should fall outside the range, admittly, I tested for +1 minute (17:43)

Comment: Yes, 17:43 will fall out of the range. The point is that the original code of OP handles 17:42:30 slightly different (although this might be not the intention of the OP himself) so I tried to handle that in my answer, too. But probably he has not thought much about this tiny hair to split. I am also wondering why he uses such a time like 17:42 (and not for example 17:45) - use-case?

Comment: @MenoHochschild I kind of skipped the code (as it was a mess) and went straight for *"Friday 17:42 and Sunday 17:42"* - nice to see the requirements don't meet the exceptions :P

Comment: @MenoHochschild It's for testing purposes. This code is a part of a selenium test. That's why I'm using 17:42, not 18:00 :)

Answer (score 0):

With `Calendar` you can know what `DAY_OF_WEEK` is the given date, then simply check the hours:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// in friday the hour must be greater than 17:42
if (dayOfWeek == 5 && ((hour > 17) || (hour == 17 && minute >= 42)) {
    // successss!!
}
// days from 1 to 7... saturday(6) all day
if (dayOfWeek == 6) {
    // successss!!
}
// sunday hour must be lower than 17:42
if (dayOfWeek == 7 && ((hour < 17) || (hour == 17 && minute <= 42)) {
    // successss!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution using **old Java** would look like this:

```
// current timestamp
GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();

// specify ISO-week (you are searching for friday until sunday in this order)
gcal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
gcal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

// sunday at 17:43
GregorianCalendar sunday = (GregorianCalendar) gcal.clone();
sunday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
sunday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
sunday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
sunday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
sunday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// friday at 17:42
GregorianCalendar friday = (GregorianCalendar) sunday.clone();
friday.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
friday.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);

// logging for test purposes
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println(f.format(friday.getTime()));
System.out.println(f.format(gcal.getTime()));
System.out.println(f.format(sunday.getTime()));

// result (assumption: half-open-interval)
boolean withinTimeWindow = !gcal.before(friday) && gcal.before(sunday);
```

**Java-8** offers a shorter approach (assuming ISO-weekmodel):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime friday = now.with(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY).toLocalDate().atTime(17, 42);
LocalDateTime sunday = friday.plusDays(2).plusMinutes(1);
boolean withinTimeWindow = !now.isBefore(friday) && now.isBefore(sunday);
```

Finally your equivalent evaluation can look like this:

```
  if (!withinTimeWindow) {
        if (combined != 0) {
            return badge == 1;
        } else {
            return badge == product;
        }
  } else {
        return badge == 0;
  }
```