# Error on converting last modified date

Tags: java

Im working on a program which tells if the last modified date of a file is in the range of the date From and date To and if it is inside the range it will copy but im having an error

```
      File src = new File(sourcefile + File.separator + strErrorFile[i]);
    if(sourcefile.isDirectory())
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> alDateList = date(strList1);
        int intDateFrom1 = alDateList.get(0);
        int intDateTo1 = alDateList.get(1);
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        System.out.println("After Format : " + sdf.format(src.lastModified()));
    try
    {
        lastDate = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(src.lastModified())); //line 362
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
        if(intDateFrom1 <= lastDate && intDateTo1 >= lastDate)
    {
             //copy
    }
    }
```

**error**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "09/10/2015"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication$4.widgetSelected(FortryApplication.java:362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.open(FortryApplication.java:56)
at org.eclipse.wb.swt.FortryApplication.main(FortryApplication.java:610)
```

Comment: this is not a valid integer --> "09/10/2015", what you can do it to split the string with the delimiter "/" and then concatenate each element within the array to make the number "091015". Note if you convert this to integer the leading zero will be removed.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw how can i change it? Sorry just new

Comment: see my answer for further details.

Comment: Okay, if you're new, you need to go read the API docs on each of objects you're using. What is SimpleDateFormat#format actually do? What is File#lastModified actually returning? Rather the just guessing and playing code together, try and understand what each of these are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "09/10/2015"

this is not a valid integer, hence the error.

One approach which you can take is to use the **[`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))** method to replace every instance of `/` with the empty string `""` which should essentially leave us with `09102015`.

**note** - when you parse this to an integer the leading zero (`0`) will be removed.

Example:

```
String data = sdf.format(src.lastModified());
```

then you can do:

```
lastDate = Integer.parseInt(data.replaceAll("/",""));
```

Comment: but how can i do it without the StringBuilder?

Comment: you can, but concatenating strings "+=" within a for loop is an overhead. StringBuilder is  simply a mutable string, so, I don't see a problem with it and anyway we're turning the StringBuilder back to string for parsing.

Comment: So, you have used `String#replaceAll` instead of a loop

Comment: @MadProgrammer true that is definitely a better solution, I'll update my post.

Comment: @abrakadabarahastags see update for another solution without using StringBuilder

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I tried that before using replaceAll but i dont know how to add 0 "9102015"

Comment: @abrakadabarahastags the answer is no you cannot add a leading 0 to an integer, you can either represent the date as a string and keep the leading 0 or use integer and lose the leading 0 that's the only two options you have. Also if the solution has solved your problem, don't forget to mark as accepted :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a step back and look at what you need and what you have.

You don't want to convert the `lastModified` value to a `String` (via `DateFormatter`) because it doesn't give you anything of real value, not when you consider there is an entire API dedicated to working with date/time

Let's start by having a look at [File#lastModified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified--)

The JavaDocs state that it returns:

> A long value representing the time the file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970), or 0L if the file does not exist or if an I/O error occurs

Okay, this is actually good, because you can use this value to generate a `LocalDateTime` object...

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(new Date(src.lastModified()).toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

why would you want to do this?  Because `LocalDateTime` has methods which makes it easy to compare against other `LocalDateTime` objects...

```
    LocalDateTime from = ...;
    LocalDateTime to = ...;

    if (ldt.isAfter(from) && ldt.isBefore(to)) {
        //between...
    }
```

You can also use `LocalDateTime#equals` to compare if the two dates are equal.

If you don't need the "time" component, you can use `LocalDateTime#toLocalDate` to get a date (without time) based object, but the comparison process is basically the same

You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044827/how-to-determine-a-date-in-between-friday-and-sunday-of-the-week-at-a-particular/31045131#31045131) which contains the overall logic for determining if a date/time values is between two given date/time values