# Transform and Get DateTime in UTC+0 in android java and compare DateTime's

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar, utc

I read a lot of answers to similar questions, but I couldn't find what I intend to do.

I'm developing an android application that I need to check if the current device DateTime (variable TimeZone) are between two DateTimes (specified in UTC+0).

Here a pseudo example:

```
if( (UTC+0 DateTime of actual week friday at 23:00:00) 
    < 
    (device DateTime transformed to UTC+0)
    <
    (UTC+0 DateTime of actual week sunday at 23:00:00) )
{
    #some code here
}
```

I don't know how to obtain the first and third DateTimes, I can get the day with:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
if(Calendar.FRIDAY < c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) < Calendar.SUNDAY)
```

but I still need the DateTime of the actual week friday and sunday at 23:00:00 specified in UTC+0.

I want to transform the actual device DateTime to UTC+0 before the comparision, I tried with **Calendar** and **Joda Time** utils but I couldn't find a simple way to obtain the current UTC+0 DateTime and also transform a non UTC+0 DateTime to UTC+0.

I'm sure it must be very simple but can't find the way.

Comment: Date objects don't care about timezone.

Comment: @njzk2 calendar.getTime() returns my device time, I'm in a UTC+1 TimeZone with DST. Gives me at this moment "sunday 00:21:00" and I want to get UTC+0 time, so I want "saturday 22:21:00".

Comment: that's the same date. it is just a matter of how you format it.

Comment: @njzk2 can you post an example please?

Comment: @njzk2 Do you mean that java understands that '2015-08-02 T00:50:00 GMT+0200' equals to '2015-08-01 T22:50:00 GMT+0000' ?

Comment: they are represented by exactly the same `Date` object, which is only a timestamp. The timezone is used only for the `Calendar` object, and when parsing and formatting dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Comparison Methods: `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isEqual`

You are working too hard.

You need not make time zone adjustments when comparing [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) handles that for you automatically. Internally Joda-Time tracks a DateTime as a number of milliseconds fro the [epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So comparing to see which comes before or later is easy.

Just call the comparison methods on [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), [`isBefore`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isBefore-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-), [`isAfter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfter-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-), and [`isEqual`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isEqual-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-).

```
Boolean inRange = ( x.isAfter( start ) || x.isEqual( start ) ) && x.isBefore ( stop ) ;
```

If the DateTime objects happen to all have the same time zone ([`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)), you make use of the handy [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class.

```
Interval interval = new Interval( start , stop ) ;
Boolean inRange = interval.contains( x ) ;
```

As for finding the next/last Monday, Sunday, whatever, search StackOverflow as that has been addressed before many times (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636038/642706)), as have all the topics in your Question actually. Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20677541/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25255811/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31044827/642706).

Both my code above and the `Interval` class use the "Half-Open" approach in their comparison logic. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. [Search StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20date%20half-open) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for explain it, now I understand it better :)

Comment: @GerardReches Good. In the future, please search StackOverflow.com before posting. In particular now, you should search for "half-open" to learn about the logic of the in-range testing in my code above and also used by that `Interval` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();            
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)");
```

Output : Sun Jul 26 2015 04:33:19 GMT+0530 (IST)

this will give you some idea

**EDITED**

use this

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

it will work you can initialize it with any timezone as

```
DateTime.now(DateTimeZone zone)
```

try this also

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
```

Comment: This gives a non UTC/GMT+0 DateTime. How to transform to GMT+0 without knowing that your GMT is +0530? Or how to do that DateTime.now returns a GMT+0 DateTime?

Comment: looking into it..will get back to you soon

Comment: use this DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ); it will work

you can initialize it with any timezone as DateTime.now(DateTimeZone zone)  

try this also

DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );

Comment: Works with this! DateTime currentTime= DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));

Comment: What "DateTime" class is this? What package? If this is Joda-Time, then this code is incorrect. You do not use SimpleDateFormat class with Joda-Time. Joda-Time has its own formatters.

Comment: DateTime is from jodatime and both belong to JodaTime these are the package:org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;,org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; it works properly i have used it and it works great..you can use compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.1' as a better and more efficient version of JodaTime

Comment: @AdityaChauhan No, the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) shown in your Answer does *not* come from those packages you mentioned, is *not* a part of Joda-Time, and should *not* be used with [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/field/DelegatedDurationField.html) objects.